# Computational Methods for Determining Stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

For a nonlinear system $\dot{x} =f(x,\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a parameter, with fixed points $x^*$ such that $f(x^*,\alpha) = 0$, what methods are there for computationally determining the stability of the fixed points?

Specifically in the case where the eigenvalues of the jacobian are all real and negative except one which is zero, for all values of the parameter $\alpha$.

Reducing the system down to its center manifold and examining the stability in that way is analytically difficult, which is why I am seeking computational methods.

Comment: Well, you don't have to recompute the full center manifold of equilbrium for each value of parameters. I suggest to write (analytically) first two-three terms of Taylor expansion of vector field along central manifold of such equilibria. They would depend on partial derivatives of $f(x, \alpha)$ w.r.t. to $x$ in some predictable fashion. If your equilibria are not very degenerate these terms would be enough to conclude the stability of equilibrium.